# Getting the process ID when launching a process via the C# Process class

Tags: c#, process, vlc

I am starting a VLC job to record some streaming audio from within a c# function as follows (the actual args aren't relevant to the question):

```
 Process proc = new Process();
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe";
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "someArgs";
 proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 proc.Start();
```

If all works correctly, the Start() function returns immediately and a process is started locally (i.e. VLC).

- How can I get the process ID of this VLC job so I can kill it later? Using proc.Close() closes the process, but does not terminate the VLC job.
- What *is* the most effective way to kill the VLC job? I have admin privilege locally.
- How can I test that the job did start correctly? Is there some status flag on the proc object I can test?

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID should be in your process object as proc.Id.

You can kill it with proc.Kill().

If there is a problem launching the process it will throw an exception (most likely a Win32Exception or an InvalidOperationException; see the help.)